# How can I send multiple logs to a single CloudWatch log stream using the AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Are there any code examples on how to send multiple logs to a single CloudWatch log stream using the `PutLogEvent` API in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`PutLogEvents`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudWatchLogs/MCloudWatchLogsPutLogEventsPutLogEventsRequest.html) method on the `AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient` class to send multiple logs (commonly referred to as a *batch*) to a single CloudWatch log stream.

You'll need to construct a [`PutLogEventsRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudWatchLogs/TPutLogEventsRequest.html), which has 3 properties:

- `LogGroupName` (`string`)
- `LogStreamName` (`string`)
- `LogEvents` (`List<InputLogEvent>`, which is essentially a list of `Message` and `Timestamp` combinations)

Putting all of that together, this should be a good starting point:

```cs
using Amazon.CloudWatchLogs;
using Amazon.CloudWatchLogs.Model;

var client = new AmazonCloudWatchLogsClient();

var request = new PutLogEventsRequest
{
    LogGroupName = "your-log-group",
    LogStreamName = "your-log-stream",
    LogEvents = new List<InputLogEvent>
    {
        new InputLogEvent { Message = "Message 1", Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new InputLogEvent { Message = "Message 2", Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow }
    }
};

var response = await client.PutLogEventsAsync(request);

var secondRequest = new PutLogEventsRequest
{
    LogGroupName = "your-log-group",
    LogStreamName = "your-log-stream",
    LogEvents = new List<InputLogEvent>
    {
        new InputLogEvent { Message = "Message 3", Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow },
        new InputLogEvent { Message = "Message 4", Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow }
    }
};

var secondResponse = await client.PutLogEventsAsync(secondRequest);
```